# Unable to go inside a running docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I am using ubuntu 22.04 lts as a sudo user.

I made a react application and then I created a image and ran it in a container successfully. But i want to go inside the container for which i ran the below command:

```
docker exec -it e448b7024af bash
```

but i got the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container e448b7024af19a0bb is not running
```

I ran the below command to check if container is running:

```
docker ps
// i got my container in the list
// also i did some actions in react application to double check if conatiner was working and it worked perfectly
```

below is the output for the above command:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
56f8042d2f1   react_d   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   youthful_sammet
```

then based on some other solution i tried the below command:

```
 docker run -it e448b7024af /bin/bash
```

and i got the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'e448b7024af:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for e448b70254af, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

then i tried the following command based on some solution i found:

```
docker pull e448b7024af:latest
```

but i got the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for e448b7024af, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

i also tried:

```
docker exec -it 568f8042d2f1 bash
```

and i got the following error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY /package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

My container is working properly but i am unable to get inside of the container. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: would be useful if you were to show the actual output of docker ps

Comment: I have added the actual output for docker ps. Check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output from `docker ps`, your container id is `56f8042d2f1` and not `e448b7024af` which I suspect might be your image id or a container id from a previous run.

Another thing is that `bash` isn't installed in Alpine images by default. You can use `sh` instead.

You can use the more human-friendly container name of `youthful_sammet` in your command and do

```
docker exec -it youthful_sammet sh
```

or, if you prefer the id

```
docker exec -it 56f8042d2f1 sh
```

Comment: ```OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown``` I got the following error. I am in my root directory for client. And while running the container i forgot to custom name the container so it is default name from docker.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that it was an Alpine image. `bash` isn't install in Alpine images by default. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong container identifier in the docker exec command as when you do docker ps the container id is different and you are using the wrong one.
I personally use the container name as identifier it is easy to remember.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but you have pointed out the issue with no real solution. Maybe add some the command needed to solve the specific issue, which will improve the answer overall.